# LWC Wrapper List Update not reflecting in client side JS or Apex

Tags: lightning-web-components, wrapper-class, lwc-wire-adapter, inputcheckboxes

I have an LWC as shown in below diagram.

[image]

Whenever I update these checkboxes these changes are not being communicated to JS property variable any help would be really appriciated.

Html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="divcenter">SalesforceCodex Field's Access Explorer</div>

        <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
                    <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                           <lightning-combobox name="objectName" 
                            label="Object"
                            value="" 
                            placeholder="Select Object" 
                            options={objects} 
                            onchange={handleObjectChange}
                            required></lightning-combobox>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                    <lightning-layout-item size="2" padding="around-small">
                            <lightning-combobox
                            name="Fields"
                            label="Fields"
                            value=""
                            placeholder="Select Field"
                            options={fields}
                            onchange={handleFieldChange}
                            required
                    ></lightning-combobox>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                    <lightning-layout-item>
                        <lightning-button
                        variant="brand" 
                        label="Brand" 
                        title="Primary action" 
                        onclick={savePermissionChange} 
                        class="slds-m-left_x-small"
                        ></lightning-button>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
        <br/>
        <div>
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="PermissionSet Name">PermissionSet Name</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Read">Read</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Write">Write</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <template for:each={permissions} for:item="perm">
                        <tr key={perm.permissionSetId}>
                            <td class="" scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate">{perm.permissionSetName}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="" scope="col">
                                <template if:true={perm.readPermission}>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate"><input type="checkbox" checked value={perm.readPermission} onchange={onPermChange}></input> </div>
                                </template>
                                <template if:false={perm.readPermission}>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate"><input type="checkbox" value={perm.readPermission} onchange={onPermChange}></input> </div>
                                </template>
                            </td>
                            <td class="" scope="col">
                                <!--<div class="slds-truncate">{perm.writePermission}<input type="checkbox" value={perm.writePermission} /></div>-->
                                <template if:true={perm.writePermission}>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate"><input type="checkbox" checked value={perm.writePermission} onchange={onPermChange}></input> </div>
                                </template>
                                <template if:false={perm.writePermission}>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate"><input type="checkbox" value={perm.writePermission} onchange={onPermChange}></input> </div>
                                </template>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS Controller

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';

import getObjects from '@salesforce/apex/permissionController.getAllObject';
import getFields from '@salesforce/apex/permissionController.getAllFields';
import getPermissionSets from '@salesforce/apex/permissionController.permissionSets';
import savePermissionSets from '@salesforce/apex/permissionController.savePermission';

export default class FieldAndObjectPermissioner extends LightningElement {
    @track objects = [];
    @track fields = [];
    @track permissions = [];
    @track objAPI = '';
    @track fldAPI = '';
    @track updateResult = '';

    @wire(getObjects)
    wiredMethod({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.dataArray = data;
            let tempArray = [];
            this.dataArray.forEach(function (element) {
                var option=
                {
                    label:element,
                    value:element
                };
                tempArray.push(option);
            });
            this.objects=tempArray;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    } 

    handleObjectChange(event)
    {   
        const selectedOption = event.detail.value; 

        this.objAPI = event.detail.value; 

        getFields({ objectName: selectedOption})
        .then(result => {
            this.dataArray = result;
            let tempArray = [];
            this.dataArray.forEach(function (element) {
                var option=
                {
                    label:element.Label,
                    value:element.Name
                };
                tempArray.push(option);
            });
            this.fields=tempArray;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });

    }
    handleFieldChange(event){
        const selectedOption1 = event.detail.value;

        this.fldAPI = selectedOption1;

        getPermissionSets({fieldAPI : this.fldAPI, objectAPI : this.objAPI})
        .then(result => {
            /*this.dataArray = result;
            let tempArray = [];
            this.dataArray.forEach(function(element){
                tempArray.push(element);
            }); */              
            this.permissions = result;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });
    }

    onPermChange(event){
        alert(JSON.stringify(event.target.dataset.permissionSetName));
    }

    savePermissionChange(event){
        alert(JSON.stringify(this.permissions[0]));
        savePermissionSets({updatedPermission : this.permissions})
        .then(result => {
            this.updateResult = result;
            alert(this.updateResult);
        })
        .catch(error => {

        });
    }
}
```

Apex Controller

```
public with sharing class permissionController {
    public permissionController() {

    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static string savePermission(List<fieldAndPermission> updatedPermission){
        system.debug('updated Permission --- '+updatedPermission[1]);
        string abc = string.valueOf(updatedPermission[1]);
        return abc;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<fieldAndPermission> permissionSets(string fieldAPI, string objectAPI){

        string objectAndField = objectAPI+'.'+fieldAPI;
        map<Id,FieldPermissions> permissionSetAndFieldPermMap = new map<Id,FieldPermissions>();
        for(FieldPermissions fps : [Select Id,PermissionsEdit,PermissionsRead,ParentId from FieldPermissions WHERE 
                                    Field =:objectAndField AND 
                                    SobjectType =: objectAPI]){
            permissionSetAndFieldPermMap.put(fps.ParentId,fps);
        }

        List<fieldAndPermission> fp = new List<fieldAndPermission>();
        map<Id,PermissionSet> permissionSetMap = new map<Id,PermissionSet>([Select Id,Name from PermissionSet WHERE isCustom = true]);       
        for(PermissionSet ps : permissionSetMap.values()){
            fieldAndPermission per = new fieldAndPermission();
            per.permissionSetName = ps.name;
            per.permissionSetId = ps.Id;
            per.readPermission = permissionSetAndFieldPermMap.containsKey(ps.Id) ? permissionSetAndFieldPermMap.get(ps.Id).PermissionsRead : false ;
            per.writePermission = permissionSetAndFieldPermMap.containsKey(ps.Id) ? permissionSetAndFieldPermMap.get(ps.Id).PermissionsEdit : false ;

            fp.add(per);
        }
        return fp;
    }

    @Auraenabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<string> getAllObject(){
        List<string> objectList = new List<string>();

        List<Schema.SObjectType> objects = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();

        for(integer i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i++){
            string objName = objects[i].getDescribe().getName();
            if((!objName.containsignorecase('history') && !objName.containsignorecase('tag')&&
                !objName.containsignorecase('share') && !objName.containsignorecase('feed')) || 
                objName.toLowerCase().right(3) ==  '__c'){
                    objectList.add(objName);
            }
        }
        return objectList;
    }

    @Auraenabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<FieldWrap> getAllFields(string objectName)
    {
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
        Schema.SObjectType ctype = gd.get(objectName); 
        Map<String, Schema.SobjectField> fmap = ctype.getDescribe().fields.getMap();   
        List<FieldWrap> strList = new List<FieldWrap>();
        for(String fieldName: fmap.keySet()) {
            FieldWrap wmp = new FieldWrap();
            wmp.name = fieldName;
            wmp.label = fmap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();        
            strList.add(wmp);
        }
        return strList;
    }

    public class FieldWrap
    {
        @Auraenabled
        public string Name{get;set;}
        @Auraenabled
        public string Label{get;set;}
    }

    public class fieldAndPermission{
        @AuraEnabled
        public string permissionSetName{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public string permissionSetId{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled 
        public boolean readPermission{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled 
        public boolean writePermission{get;set;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Firstly, input type checkbox will show you true or false automatically and you need not have separate **template if:true**.
2. For checkbox, you should use `checked` attribute for binding boolean and not `value`.
3. You can bind a formula to `checked` property.
4. Also, LWC components are **1-way** binding. So, even if it shows the checked or not based on initial formula, further changes will not be reflected in the binded property. You need to use `onchange` to set the property.

If you consider below lines:

```
<td class="" scope="col">
    <template if:true={perm.readPermission}>
        <div class="slds-truncate"><input type="checkbox" checked value={perm.readPermission} onchange={onPermChange}></input> </div>
    </template>
    <template if:false={perm.readPermission}>
        <div class="slds-truncate"><input type="checkbox" value={perm.readPermission} onchange={onPermChange}></input> </div>
    </template>
</td>
<td class="" scope="col">
    <!--<div class="slds-truncate">{perm.writePermission}<input type="checkbox" value={perm.writePermission} /></div>-->
    <template if:true={perm.writePermission}>
        <div class="slds-truncate"><input type="checkbox" checked value={perm.writePermission} onchange={onPermChange}></input> </div>
    </template>
    <template if:false={perm.writePermission}>
        <div class="slds-truncate"><input type="checkbox" value={perm.writePermission} onchange={onPermChange}></input> </div>
    </template>
</td>
```

Below is how you can write above html:

```
<td class="" scope="col">
    <div class="slds-truncate"><input type="checkbox" data-id={perm.permissionSetId} checked={perm.readPermission} onchange={onReadPermChange}></input> </div>
</td>
<td class="" scope="col">
    <div class="slds-truncate"><input type="checkbox" data-id={perm.permissionSetId} checked={perm.writePermission} onchange={onWritePermChange}></input> </div>
</td>
```

Then you need to get the `checked` property in `onchange` handler:

```
onReadPermChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.checked);
    let currentItem = this.permissions.find(perm=>perm.permissionSetId===event.currentTarget.dataset.id);
    currentItem.readPermission = event.target.checked;
}

onWritePermChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.checked);
    let currentItem = this.permissions.find(perm=>perm.permissionSetId===event.currentTarget.dataset.id);
    currentItem.writePermission = event.target.checked;
}
```

[Playground example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/pb87O9nf6/1/edit) for your understanding

Comment: Thank you for your help :)